# Which version of pig should use for hbase 0.98.8

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig

I have `hadoop 2.5.1` installed

`Hive` version is `0.13.1`

`Pig` version is `0.13.0`

Habse version is 0.98.8

If I want to load files from HDFS into habase using pig then will my pig version work fine?

For now I am facing issue as follows:

```
2014-12-24 16:11:24,783 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.equals([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you build pig with the following options:

```
-Dhbaseversion=95 -Dhadoopversion=23 -Dprotobuf-java.version=2.5.0
```

Comment: How to build pig? How to sepecify above options? I am new to pig.

Comment: Why I need to build pig?
I am able to run simple pig script. But I am not able to store data to hbase.

Comment: because there are breaking changes between some versions of hadoop and hbase. You need to build it against the versions you are using.